# Creating a Website Landing Page with Inline Elements

Tags: html, css, header, block, element

I am trying to create a header with two inline elements in it, picture and text. What I'm going for (I circled the two elements):

[image: Landing Page with Inline Elements]

How would I go about this? I tried floating the text to the right, but it takes up the whole screen (not resizing).

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried to date. Also, you are best using flexbox for this sort of layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, there should be an image towards the left and towards the right end of the image, there should be a descriptive text?

If that is the case, (among the many) one option is to give a `margin-left` to the `element` which holds the text and we should know the *size* of the image to do it correctly:

```css
.header {
  background: url(" http://placehold.it/350x350") no-repeat;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 355px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. End!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, but using a grid system you'd put the two objects in a row then float them left like this:

```css
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

.row {
width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.onehalf {
width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="onehalf">THING ONE</div>
  <div class="onehalf">THING TWO</div>
</div>
```